# Tmux option window-status-activity-style refuses to override window-status-format

Tags: tmux

I'm trying to have tmux draw my attention to background windows when they have new activity in them, but I'm having trouble with the various *-activity-* options.  It seems as though any setting I give them is always ignored if the window-status-format string contains any value for that setting.  E.g. :

```
# Set window notifications
setw -g monitor-activity on
set-option -gw window-status-activity-style fg=white,bg=red,blink

...

setw -g window-status-format "#[fg=colour231,bg=colour233] #I :#[fg=colour231,bg=colour233] #W "
```

With the above in my .tmux.conf, the color of the window-status won't change at all.  I originally only had the `fg` and `bg` options in there and thought I was just setting it wrong, but adding the `blink` attribute does make the window-status blink on activity.  I have even tried passing the `-a` flag to

`set-option -agw window-status-activity-style fg=white,bg=red,blink`

but it made no difference, which is what you'd expect.

Comment: Not sure if this is related, but what's with the redundant colour instructions in the last line?

Comment: If I want the index and the window name to be different colors, I just change the corresponding color instruction.  I happen to have them the same at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've discovered the root of my problem.  The `window-status-activity-style` *is* going into affect, but `window-status-format` will take priority such that the activity style can't overwrite anything that is explicitly set in the format.  I got blinking to work by setting it in the activity style and making sure that there is nothing to prevent blinking in the format.

If I want it to change font color upon activity, I'll have to set a font color in the activity style, and make sure that there is no font color mentioned in the format.  I can make non-activity windows still appear as intended by making the default window tittle font color the same as what I would have put in the format.

Answer (score 1):

try it with this :

blinking works for me.. at least in xterm (not urxvt :/)...

```
20 set -g window-status-format " #{?window_activity_flag, #[fg=colour231]#[blink],#[fg=colour245]}#{?window_bell_flag,#[fg=colour01]#[blink],#[fg=colour245]} #W "
21 set -g window-status-style 'bg=colour232'
22 set -g window-status-activity-style 'bg=colour232,fg=colour247,blink'
23 set -g window-status-bell-style 'bg=colour232,fg=colour01,blink'
24 set -g window-status-current-style 'bg=colour232,fg=colour09'
25 set -g monitor-activity on
```